# Обязательна ли постановка тире

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли написано предложение:

***Мне пришлось долго доказывать роботу, что я (—) не робот.***

Требуется ли в данном случае постановка тире и почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Допускаются оба варианта.**

Обычно после местоимения тире не ставится, но возможна постановка авторского (интонационного)  тире, при котором местоимение в роли подлежащего логически выделено.

[Розенталь. § 5. Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92#pp92)

8) Если подлежащее выражено личным местоимением, а сказуемое — формой именительного падежа существительного, тире между ними обычно не ставится: Он порча, он чума, он язва здешних мест (Кр.); Я честный человек и никогда не говорю комплиментов (Ч.).
Однако тире в этом случае ставится:
1) при логическом подчеркивании: Я — страница твоему перу. Всё приму. Я белая страница. Я — хранитель твоему добру… (Цв.);